# Qt widgets project

Tags: qt

When I looked at some of the GUI examples, I noticed some of the projects contains Forms folder and XXXX.ui files allowing user to modify the layout on the Design screen. But some of them don't have Forms folder and ui files but still have GUI to display.

So the GUI display on above latter cases are hand-coded and the other is using Designer. Is there a way to convert these two kind of projects from one to another?

Comment: You want the conversion to be automatic, right? Obviously you can always convert it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Those .ui files are used by the User Interface Compiler[1] to generate some file named ui_formname.h that contains a class, Formname, inside the Ui namespace. So ultimately, everything resumes to C++ code

[1] http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html

Comment: While ui files can also be loaded at runtime using QUiLoader - but that's a rather rare use case in comparison.